# В консоли выводятся знаки вопроса

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql

Я пишу api используя golang и postgres в качестве базы данных, при вводе в консоль команды:

```
    migrate -path migrations -database "postgres://localhost/restapi_dev?sslmode=disable" up
```

выдаётся ошибка:

```
   error: pq: ������������ "User" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)
```

также это происходит после попытки запустить api, понимаю, что проблема в кодировке, но её изменение не помогает, в остальном отображение нормальное.